# Null value to an Int field

Tags: java, oracle, entity, spring-data-neo4j

I have an entity class which has an int field , in the table the cloumn type is Number (10,0). In the table default value is "NULL". Using Spring data JPA when I try select query using jpa I am getting below errors.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.test.app.entity.TestProject.baseUserIdNumber to null value
```

I cannot change anything in the table as this is already created and used in the production. Anything I can do with Entity class or JPQL

```
@Entity
public class TestProject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int projectId;
    private String description;
    private String name;
    private int seqNumber
    private LocalDate startDateTime;
    private LocalDate endDateTime;
    @Column(name = "baseUserIdNumber")
    private int myfield;
    private String projStatus;



constructors ()
getters()
Setters()


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just define the field with a default value and define as int instead of Integer so that it doesn't accept NULL values.

```java
@Column(name = "my_column")
private int myField = 0;
```

Comment: Why wasn't it working? Update the main post then with your entire class that represents the table.

Comment: Sure. I will do that.

Comment: I changed myField data type to BigDecimal and it worked. Since the table properties shows the data type of the field as Number (10,0), I simply guessed this may be a decimal field.

Comment: Entity class is added. When I change int to BigDecimal it worked fine. It will be helpful if I am able to use int here.

Comment: Well, you could probably use Integer instead of int if you expect/need a NULL value.

Comment: Done! @JAVA_CAT

Comment: Thanks @Jason.  The above solution to set the int to zero did not work for me, but using Integer instead of int did, thanks for suggesting that.

Answer (score 0):

There's something strange in what you described.

- there's a table
- it has a column whose datatype is `number(10, 0)`
- its default value is `null`

  - well, yes - if it isn't specified, it really is `null`
- code you executed returns

  > Can not set (...) to null value

That just doesn't make sense. If its default value is `null`, how come you can't set it to `null`? Isn't the table set to **not null**, perhaps?

This is Oracle code, but the error message is similar to what you got:

```
SQL> create table test (id number(10, 0) not null, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 1, 'Little' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'Foot'   from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> update test set id = null where id = 1;
update test set id = null where id = 1
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01407: cannot update ("SCOTT"."TEST"."ID") to NULL
```

As you can't do anything with the table (as it is used in production), all you can do is **not** trying to set it to `null` (no matter which tool or language you use).

Comment: I am getting the error when I try to fetch data from table. Value in the table for that particular field is null.  Null value is getting assigned to primitive int. May be that is the problem?

Comment: In your example you set the field as not null. In my case the default value is null.

Comment: Fetch? Oh. It looked like update/insert to me. As of my example: yes, that's what I though while reading the problem you described.

Comment: I see; you said that it works with BigDecimal. Can't you keep using it? Unfortunately, I don't know Java so I can't help much about it.